# Unable to install Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10

I was trying to install visual studio 2015 community edition on Windows 10 Enterprise system from downloaded ISO file from official website. There occurred an error showing the installation failed. The error was like the one shown below in the snapshot:

[image]

Again I tried to install Windows 10 SDK Manually and tried to open the UWP Project. It shows "This project requires a Visual Studio update to load. Right click on project and choose Download Update". I tried everything but it fails to open the project.

I tried to install the Visual Studio via online installer, but it failed.

I am unable to identify where is the issue. Any help would be appreciable !

Comment: Hi Vedank, have you been able to investigate the log file?

Comment: error  15605 = ERROR_INSTALL_NETWORK_FAILURE (There was a problem downloading your product). Try it again, you have some network issues

Comment: Can you create new blank universal app?

Comment: any update? Were you able to install the Emulators?